# line break in subfigure caption with proper "hang" alignment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, line-breaking, subfloats

I want to insert a manual line break in the subfigures captions. I have achieved this with either `\protect\\` or `\newline`. However, the second lines do not align properly. I want them to start at the same horizontal position as the text (not the number) of the first line.

Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,openright,oneside,bibliography=totoc,headsepline]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[config=altsf]{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mwe}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \captionsetup[subfloat]{format=hang,singlelinecheck=false,justification=RaggedRight}
    \centering
    \subfloat[line break should \protect\\ be here]{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-a}}
    \newline
    \subfloat[newline \newline there]{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-a}}
    \caption{Test figure.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The output looks like this:
[image]

First, the second line is not aligned like the first one (seems to be centered) and second, why are the two images not aligned? How can I achieve a line break and a hanging alignment of the second line? So, for subfigure (a) the "b" of the second line should be (horizontally) where the "l" is from the first line.
An ugly workaround would be to set `\hspace` to an appropriate value instead of using a line break command. But I hope there is a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the problem is that `singlelinecheck=false` doesn't work if the `subfig` package is loaded with the option `[config=altsf]`. So I didn't use it:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,openright,oneside,bibliography=totoc,headsepline]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage
%[config=altsf]
{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mwe}


\begin{document}


\begin{figure}
    \captionsetup[subfloat]{margin=10pt,format=hang,singlelinecheck=false,justification=RaggedRight}
    \centering
    \subfloat[line break should \protect\\ be here]{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-a}}

    \subfloat[newline \newline
    there]{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-a}}
    \caption{Test figure.}
\end{figure}



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I would like to keep the old package as well. I have a lot of figures and only recently switched to the newer 'subfig' package and I do not want to reorientate all the older figures using the 'subfigure' package so that they would look with the newer 'subfig' package as they do now.

Comment: Hi @aquila I am not suggesting to switch to `subfig`! It was already used in your code.

Comment: Hi @Hafid Boukhoulda, you are right. But without the option `[config=altsf]` my older figures using the `subfigure` command will not work anymore and it will not compile until I change them to `subfloat`. Or do I miss something? Maybe, I should change them it `subfloat` and realign them again.

Comment: @aquila Do you mean that you use both `subfig` and `subfigure` packages  in the same file ?

Comment: Yes, I have been using both commands. Now I changed all `\subfigure` commands to `\subfloat`. And the caption alignment now works. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @aquila pleased to know that your problem is solved!